# Need to make app's textStyle bold

Tags: text, fonts

I managed to make bold text by adding android:textStyle="bold" to all sections of my xml file i.e EditText, Button, TextView, etc. But is there a way to make it global so that it affects the entire application? Or do I have to always specify the fields I want bold? I hope this makes sense. Thank you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#b5b3b3"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:hint="Enter Text Here" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Show Items" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Items will display here" 
    android:color="#FFF8AA"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:orientation="vertical" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="SaveText" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Number of Items in Array" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your application is using PhoneGap, you can specify the font weight in a .css file. Just attach the css to all your pages with the following code.

```
body
{
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

If you're not using PhoneGap, I'm afraid I can't help you.

Comment: I am actually using Eclipse Juno and coding in Java. Will that work the same way?